# Credentials setup issue when using Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, credentials

I did the following code to post a message on Twitter using Twitter4j on Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
String consumerKey = ".....";
String consumerSecret = "....";
String accessToken = "....";
String accessTokenSecret = "....";

ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
        .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

//Posting a Tweet
twitter.updateStatus("Hello , This is a sample tweet");

}
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following). 
message - SSL is required
code - 92

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0f7b8a6a
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-0f7b8a6a], statusCode=403, message=SSL is required, code=92, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.0}
```

I get the same error whether I try to get a timeline or to make a query or to send a post.

I think I could not have hit any limit, because this is the first try I'm doing from Java.
Does someone have an idea about the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

You must be using an older version of Twitter4J.

For older version of Twitter4j you have to enable `.setUseSSL(true);`

In previous versions (before 4.x - Mar, 2014), you had to select if you were going to connect to Twitter's API via an SSL or a standard request, but twitter has since turned off the ability to connect via a non-SSL connection.

In version 4.xx of twitter4j that setUseSSL(..) method has been removed and the library will use SSL by default.

Twitter changed its API to **require** SSL for user privacy reasons

> Communicating over TLS preserves user privacy by protecting
>   information between the user and the Twitter API as it travels across
>   the public Internet.

Comment: This is the correct answer and explains the reason why you would have had to set this to true if you were using an older version of Twitter4J. I'd recommend updating to the latest version if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by adding:

```
cb.setUseSSL(true);
```

I don't know exactly the explanation behind. Could someone explain ?

Comment: This method does not exist anymore in 4.0.7